# I want to align [li] with images using "swiper-master" script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to align [li] with images using "swiper-master" script.

But it is difficult to align it because I am not used to using "display: flex".

How can I arrange it like an image?

The image has been attached with below.

※I didn't speak English, so I used a translator.

So the sentence may not be smooth. Sorry!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwOaO.jpg)

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 4, 
    freeMode: true,
    mousewheel: true, 
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1
}

.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column
}

.swiper-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    transition-property: transform;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0)
    }

.swiper-slide {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition-property: transform
}

.swiper-container-3d {
    perspective: 1200px
}
```

```html
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div> 
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using `float` property you can see in below snippet .

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black
}

.li01 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 45vh;
  padding-top: 12%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.li02 {
  clear: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 45vh;
  padding-top: 12%;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.li03 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 93vh;
    padding-top: 26%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
.li04 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 93vh;
    padding-top: 26%;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li class="li01">li01</li>
  <li class="li02">li02</li>
  <li class="li03">li03</li>
  <li class="li04">li04</li>
</div>
```

I don't know how to give soft code height to `li` tag or any other so used according to viewport